# Cell update it appearance only after second click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add logic to `UITableViewCell` that  "colour" it, i mean, changes specific UI properties. However, changes appear only after second click or after table reload. This is what i tried:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
        if (selected) {
        _titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#155aa1"];
        _codeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#155aa1"];  
    } else {   
        _titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _codeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#b4b5b7"];   
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in your `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated`?

Comment: @zcui93 i have indepent class for manage UITableView delegate & data source, in which this method implemented as     [self.viewModel.cmdCellSelected execute:indexPath];

Comment: Mmmm.. MVVM? This quickly becomes a more complicated question. It seems that `setSelected` is not invoked? I think pasting your VM code here is more relevant than the current one?